# Abandoned object detection using SVM classifier. the error is: Error using svmtrain (line 254) Y and TRAINING must have the same number of rows

Tags: matlab, image-processing, svm

I am working on my project for abandoned object detection using `svm` in `matlab` and I'm totally new to it.

I have been constantly getting this error which is as follows:

```
Error using svmtrain (line 254)
Y and TRAINING must have the same number of rows.
Error in NewSVM (line 35)
SVMStruct = svmtrain(Data,class);
```

My Code:

```
imageOne = imread('D:\project\PlaneBackgound.jpg'); //Read a white image
[r,c] = size(imageOne);
imageTwo = imread('D:\d backup\my movie\sankalp 2014\IMG_6984.JPG'); //Read    reference image
resize = imresize(imageTwo,[r c/3]);//resize the image
K = imsubtract(imageOne,resize);
imshow(K);
imageTwo = rgb2gray(imageTwo);
imageTwo = resize(imageTwo,[200 200]);

readImages = dir('E:\Matlab\bin\data set\*.jpg'); //Read all the data from data set
for i = 1 : length(readImages) // read all the required images for providing to the svm, currently using only two images 
    filename = strcat('E:\Matlab\bin\data set\',readImages(i).name);
    imageRead{i} = imread(filename);
end
for i = 1:2 // using for loop, trying to convert all the images read into gray scale image and modifying the size and shape.  
    currentimage = imageRead{i};
    images{i} = currentimage;
    images{i} = im2double(images{i});
    images{i} = imresize(images{i},[200 200]);
    images{i} = rgb2gray(images{i});
    images{i} = reshape(images{i}', 1, size(images{i},1)*size(images{i},2));
end
d = size(images);

for ii=1:d
    trainData(ii,:) = images(ii);
end
class = [1 -1];
Data = str2double(trainData);
SVMStruct = svmtrain(Data,class);  // Here is where i get an error and cannot proceed any further beyond this
imageTwo = imresize(imageTwo, [200 200]);
imageTwo = reshape (imageTwo, 1, size(imageTwo,1)*size(imageTwo,2));
result = svmclassify(SVMStruct,imageTwo);
```

Comment: Read what the error is telling you, then compare what you're inputting into `svmtrain` with the typical inputs. Use the debugging tools and check the sizes and *types* of your inputs.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. I'm totally new to matlab and to these concepts. If you could be a little more explanatory would be helpful. The input which I'm passing to svmtrain function is imAges which I want to be detected. And class contains the values which I'm expecting after it is detected. I.e either 1 or -1.